# NetSuite data centers

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl, netsuite

NetSuite will be migrating our data center soon, and I was just wanting to make sure that the web service references I currently have will be ok.  I haven't been able to find anything really concrete in the documentation, but I think it's implicit.

In visual studio my web service reference is pointing at https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v20xx_y_0/netsuite.wsdl

I pretty much follow their example by making a call to

string domain = NetSuiteWebReference.getDataCenterURLs("myAccount").webservicesDomain;

But when they migrate our data center, will I then also need to update my web reference to:
https://webservices.na42.netsuite.com/wsdl/v20xx_y_0/netsuite.wsdl
?

It would make sense to *me* that domain discovery is provided from one host/location.

Comment: I think you should ask them directly.

Answer (score 1):

I did open a case/ticket and asked this same question, and they told me:

> getDataCenterURLs() would return the 'restDomain', 'systemDomain' and
>   'webservicesDomain' with respect to the datacenter of the account that
>   you specified.

I took it further and captured a getDataCenterURLs() soap post (using fiddler), and then sent that to:

- webservices.netsuite.com
- webservices.na1.netsuite.com
- webservices.na2.netsuite.com

and received the same/correct response each time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header>
        <preferences xmlns="urn:messages_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
        </preferences>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <getDataCenterUrls xmlns="urn:messages_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
            <account>1234567890</account>
        </getDataCenterUrls>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```